# How to manipulate Template element with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to manipulate inside of `<template>` element with jQuery but unfortunately some functions like `find()` don't work for child elements.

How can I replace the text of `.name` class of this template and append it to inside of another html element?

```html
<template id="conversationTemplate">
  <div class="card conversation mb-1">
    <div class="name">##name##</div>
  </div>    
</template>
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution we have here using just JQuery. Four lines, but with a few steps we can make it singleliner for those who prefer.

```js
$(() => {
  const $templateTag = $('#conversationTemplate');
  const $clonedContent = $($('#conversationTemplate').html());
  $clonedContent.find('.name').html('other text here');
  $templateTag.wrap('<template id="conversationTemplate"></div>').parent().html($clonedContent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<template id="conversationTemplate">
  <div class="card conversation mb-1">
    <div class="name">##name##</div>
  </div>    
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use jQuery selector functions directly on a template. You need to parse this first.

```js
var tpl = $('#conversationTemplate')[0].outerHTML;
$template = $($.parseXML(tpl)).contents();
console.log($template.find('.name').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<template id="conversationTemplate">
    <div class="card conversation mb-1">
        <div class="name">##name##</div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in jQuery but you don't need to. This is plain javascript that will also just work.

```
var template = document.getElementById('conversationTemplate');
var html = template.innerHTML.replace('##name##', 'Jane');
var target = document.getElementById('the-other-element-you-mention');
target.innerHTML = html;
```

It does two things you asked:

1. Gets template HTML and replaces the name.
2. Updates another element with this new HTML.